# Get Value of another row based on one column in measure - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, filtering, measure

I have a table similar to this

| Date | Category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13/1/22 | ABC | 30 |
| 13/1/22 | CAD | 20 |
| 13/1/22 | FGR | 45 |
| 13/2/22 | ABC | 25 |
| 13/2/22 | CAD | 15 |
| 13/2/22 | FGR | 60 |
| 13/2/22 | MNB | 35 |

I need to add 2 times the value of category (ABC) to other rows, my new measure should be something like if Category != ABC then new value= value+2*(ABC Value) for same date if Category= ABC then new value=value

Output:

| Date | Category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13/1/22 | ABC | 30 |
| 13/1/22 | CAD | 80 |
| 13/1/22 | FGR | 105 |
| 13/2/22 | ABC | 25 |
| 13/2/22 | CAD | 65 |
| 13/2/22 | FGR | 110 |
| 13/2/22 | MNB | 85 |

This ABC is not the value I know before it is dynamic, I will get these from some slicer. Iam not able to find solution to this anywhere.
I tried to do something by Unpivoting the table for Category column but there I faced issue with referencing column from string which is not possible for now.

Please assist. Thank you!